# Best web based SVG WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg, wysiwyg

I have a site that is in need of a drawing program. My users need to be able to draw floor plans and add text to these images. I'm wondering if anyone has come across a nice SVG WYSIWYG editor.

Otherwise I'm going to have to use a Flash or Java app which I'm not fond of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one I know is [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/). It is not nearly as powerful or mature as editors like CKEditor, TinyMCE or FCKEditor are in their field of application, and it won't be as simple to implement, since it is more a script like a component, and finally I don't know how easy it is to customize it.

But I heavily doubt that there is something similar with more comfort.

You might have a try [here](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/stable/editor/svg-editor.html) or [here](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.4/editor/svg-editor.html)  (just to mention, won't work in Internet Explorer - although the site states that it would work if you have Chrome Frame installed but I can't confirm that).

Maybe you could tell us how far this meets your requirements ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One impressive example of a polished and very intuitive webbased "drawing" app is [accidentsketch.com](http://accidentsketch.com/). Uses both svg and html.